# List comprehension in Ruby

Tags: ruby, list-comprehension

To do the equivalent of Python list comprehensions, I'm doing the following:

```
some_array.select{|x| x % 2 == 0 }.collect{|x| x * 3}
```

Is there a better way to do this...perhaps with one method call?

Comment: Both yours and glenn mcdonald's answers seem fine to me... I don't see what you'd gain by trying to be more concise than either.

Comment: this solution transverses the list two times. The inject doesn't.

Comment: Some awesome answers here but it'd be awesome too see ideas for list comprehension across multiple collections.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you really want to, you can create an Array#comprehend method like this:

```
class Array
  def comprehend(&block)
    return self if block.nil?
    self.collect(&block).compact
  end
end

some_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
new_array = some_array.comprehend {|x| x * 3 if x % 2 == 0}
puts new_array
```

Prints:

```
6
12
18
```

I would probably just do it the way you did though.

Comment: You could use compact! to optimize a bit

Comment: This isn't actually correct, consider:

```[nil, nil, nil].comprehend {|x| x }``` which returns ```[]```.

Comment: alexey, according to the docs, `compact!` returns nil instead of the array when no items are changed, so I don't think that works.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is not a new syntactical construct, so it's hardly a "comprehension". I personally don't think it's appropriate to name such a function "comprehend"

Answer (score 101):

How 'bout:

```
some_array.map {|x| x % 2 == 0 ? x * 3 : nil}.compact
```

Slightly cleaner, at least to my taste, and according to a quick benchmark test about 15% faster than your version...

Comment: as well as `some_array.map{|x| x * 3 unless x % 2}.compact`, which is arguably more readable/ruby-esque.

Comment: @nightpool `unless x%2` has no effect since 0 is truthy in ruby. See: https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362

Answer (score 34):

I made a quick benchmark comparing the three alternatives and **map-compact** really seems to be the best option.

#### Performance test (Rails)

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'performance_test_help'

class ListComprehensionTest < ActionController::PerformanceTest

  TEST_ARRAY = (1..100).to_a

  def test_map_compact
    1000.times do
      TEST_ARRAY.map{|x| x % 2 == 0 ? x * 3 : nil}.compact
    end
  end

  def test_select_map
    1000.times do
      TEST_ARRAY.select{|x| x % 2 == 0 }.map{|x| x * 3}
    end
  end

  def test_inject
    1000.times do
      TEST_ARRAY.inject([]) {|all, x| all << x*3 if x % 2 == 0; all }
    end
  end

end
```

#### Results

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -I"lib:test" "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/performance/list_comprehension_test.rb" -- --benchmark
Loaded suite /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
ListComprehensionTest#test_inject (1230 ms warmup)
           wall_time: 1221 ms
              memory: 0.00 KB
             objects: 0
             gc_runs: 0
             gc_time: 0 ms
.ListComprehensionTest#test_map_compact (860 ms warmup)
           wall_time: 855 ms
              memory: 0.00 KB
             objects: 0
             gc_runs: 0
             gc_time: 0 ms
.ListComprehensionTest#test_select_map (961 ms warmup)
           wall_time: 955 ms
              memory: 0.00 KB
             objects: 0
             gc_runs: 0
             gc_time: 0 ms
.
Finished in 66.683039 seconds.

15 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

Comment: Would be interesting to see `reduce` in this benchmark as well (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17703276).

Comment: map_compact maybe faster but it's creating a new array. inject is space efficient than map.compact and select.map

Answer (score 13):

There seems to be some confusion amongst Ruby programmers in this thread concerning what list comprehension is.  Every single response assumes some preexisting array to transform.  But list comprehension's power lies in an array created on the fly with the following syntax:

```
squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
```

The following would be an analog in Ruby (the only adequate answer in this thread, AFAIC):

```
a = Array.new(4).map{rand(2**49..2**50)}
```

In the above case, I'm creating an array of random integers, but the block could contain anything.  But this would be a Ruby list comprehension.

Comment: How would you do what the OP is trying to do?

Comment: Actually I see now the OP itself had some existing list the author wanted to transform.  But the archetypal conception of list comprehension involves creating an array/list where one didn't exist before by referencing some iteration.  But actually, some formal definitions say list comprehension can't use map at all, so even my version isn't kosher -but as close as one could get in Ruby I guess.

Comment: I don't get how your Ruby example is supposed to be an analogue of your Python example. The Ruby code should read: squares = (0..9).map { |x| x**2 }

Comment: While @michau is right, the whole point of list comprehension (which Mark neglected) is that list comprehension itself does not use not generate arrays - it uses generators and co routines to do all calculations in a streaming manner without allocating storage at all (except temp variables) until (iff) the results land in an array variable - this is the purpose of the square brackets in the python example, to collapse the comprehension to a set of results. Ruby has no facility similar to generators.

Comment: Oh yes, it has (since Ruby 2.0): squares_of_all_natural_numbers = (0..Float::INFINITY).lazy.map{|x| x**2}; p squares_of_all_natural_numbers.take(10).to_a

Comment: "Every single response assumes some preexisting array to transform." Thank you for spotting this! I have been looking for an answer like yours for some time...

Comment: While I agree that the comprehension's power is being able to create new constructs on the fly, the power is in not chaining function calls due to a syntactic feature. What you're ascribing the power of python's comprehensions is the range function, which is merely *useful* to comprehensions, not part of the syntax.

Answer (score 12):

I discussed this topic with Rein Henrichs, who tells me that the best performing solution is

```
map { ... }.compact
```

This makes good sense because it avoids building intermediate Arrays as with the immutable usage of `Enumerable#inject`, and it avoids growing the Array, which causes allocation. It's as general as any of the others unless your collection can contain nil elements.

I haven't compared this with

```
select {...}.map{...}
```

It's possible that Ruby's C implementation of `Enumerable#select` is also very good.

Answer (score 10):

I've just published the [comprehend gem](https://github.com/mdsol-share/comprehend) to RubyGems, which lets you do this:

```
require 'comprehend'

some_array.comprehend{ |x| x * 3 if x % 2 == 0 }
```

It's written in C; the array is only traversed once.

Comment: Sadly, naming something `comprehend` doesn't make it a comprehension.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative solution that will work in every implementation and run in O(n) instead of O(2n) time is:

```
some_array.inject([]){|res,x| x % 2 == 0 ? res << 3*x : res}
```

Comment: You mean it traverses the list only once. If you go by the formal definition, O(n) equals O(2n). Just nitpicking :)

Comment: @Daniel Harper :) Not only you are right, but also for the average case, transversing the list once to discard some entries, and then again to perform an operation can be acctually better in the average cases :)

Comment: In other words, you are doing `2` things `n` times instead of `1` thing `n` times and then another `1` thing `n` times :) One important advantage of `inject`/`reduce` is that it preserves any `nil` values in the input sequence which is more list-comprehensionly behaviour

Answer (score 7):

Enumerable has a `grep` method whose first argument can be a predicate proc, and whose optional second argument is a mapping function; so the following works:

```
some_array.grep(proc {|x| x % 2 == 0}) {|x| x*3}
```

This isn't as readable as a couple of other suggestions (I like anoiaque's simple `select.map` or histocrat's comprehend gem), but its strengths are that it's already part of the standard library, and is single-pass and doesn't involve creating temporary intermediate arrays, and doesn't require an out-of-bounds value like `nil` used in the `compact`-using suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

This is more concise:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].select(&:even?).map{|x| x*3}
```

Comment: Or, for even more point-free awesomeness `[1,2,3,4,5,6].select(&:even?).map(&3.method(:*))`

Answer (score 5):

Ruby 2.7 introduced `filter_map` which pretty much achieves what you want (map + compact):

```rb
some_array.filter_map { |x| x * 3 if x % 2 == 0 }
```

You can read more about it [here](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/05/25/ruby-2-7-enumerable-filter-map.html).

Answer (score 4):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].collect{|x| x * 3 if x % 2 == 0}.compact
=> [6, 12, 18]
```

That works for me. It is also clean. Yes, it's the same as `map`, but I think `collect` makes the code more understandable.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
def lazy(collection, &blk)
   collection.map{|x| blk.call(x)}.compact
end
```

Call it:

```
lazy (1..6){|x| x * 3 if x.even?}
```

Which returns:

```
=> [6, 12, 18]
```

Comment: What's wrong with defining `lazy` on Array and then: `(1..6).lazy{|x|x*3 if x.even?}`

Answer (score 2):

Like Pedro mentioned, you can fuse together the chained calls to `Enumerable#select` and `Enumerable#map`, avoiding a traversal over the selected elements. This is true because `Enumerable#select` is a specialization of fold or `inject`. I posted a [hasty introduction](http://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/a13fm/a_60_second_fusion_tutorial_for_ruby/) to the topic at the Ruby subreddit.

Manually fusing Array transformations can be tedious, so maybe someone could play with Robert Gamble's `comprehend` implementation to make this `select`/`map` pattern prettier.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution but perhaps not the best one

```
some_array.flat_map {|x| x % 2 == 0 ? [x * 3] : [] }
```

or

```
some_array.each_with_object([]) {|x, list| x % 2 == 0 ? list.push(x * 3) : nil }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to approach this:

```rb
c = -> x do $*.clear             
  if x['if'] && x[0] != 'f' .  
    y = x[0...x.index('for')]    
    x = x[x.index('for')..-1]
    (x.insert(x.index(x.split[3]) + x.split[3].length, " do $* << #{y}")
    x.insert(x.length, "end; $*")
    eval(x)
    $*)
  elsif x['if'] && x[0] == 'f'
    (x.insert(x.index(x.split[3]) + x.split[3].length, " do $* << x")
    x.insert(x.length, "end; $*")
    eval(x)
    $*)
  elsif !x['if'] && x[0] != 'f'
    y = x[0...x.index('for')]
    x = x[x.index('for')..-1]
    (x.insert(x.index(x.split[3]) + x.split[3].length, " do $* << #{y}")
    x.insert(x.length, "end; $*")
    eval(x)
    $*)
  else
    eval(x.split[3]).to_a
  end
end
```

so basically we are converting a string to proper ruby syntax for loop
then we can use python syntax in a string to do:

```
c['for x in 1..10']
c['for x in 1..10 if x.even?']
c['x**2 for x in 1..10 if x.even?']
c['x**2 for x in 1..10']

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
# [4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
# [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

or if you don't like the way the string looks or having to use a lambda we could forego the attempt to mirror python syntax and do something like this:

```
S = [for x in 0...9 do $* << x*2 if x.even? end, $*][1]
# [0, 4, 8, 12, 16]
```

Answer (score -1):

https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_list_comprehension

shameless plug for my Ruby List Comprehension gem to allow idiomatic Ruby list comprehensions

```
$l[for x in 1..10 do x + 2 end] #=> [3, 4, 5 ...]
```

Answer (score -3):

I think the most list comprehension-esque would be the following:

```
some_array.select{ |x| x * 3 if x % 2 == 0 }
```

Since Ruby allows us to place the conditional after the expression, we get syntax similar to the Python version of the list comprehension. Also, since the `select` method does not include anything that equates to `false`, all nil values are removed from the resultant list and no call to compact is necessary as would be the case if we had used `map` or `collect` instead.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. At least in Ruby 1.8.6, 
    
     [1,2,3,4,5,6].select {|x| x * 3 if x % 2 == 0}

evaluates to

    [2, 4, 6]

Enumerable#select only cares about whether the block evaluates to true or false, not what value it outputs, AFAIK.