# In Ruby, is there an Array method that combines 'select' and 'map'?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby array containing some string values.  I need to:

1. Find all elements that match some predicate
2. Run the matching elements through a transformation
3. Return the results as an array

Right now my solution looks like this:

```
def example
  matchingLines = @lines.select{ |line| ... }
  results = matchingLines.map{ |line| ... }
  return results.uniq.sort
end
```

Is there an Array or Enumerable method that combines select and map into a single logical statement?

Comment: Ruby 2.7 is introducing `filter_map` for this exact purpose. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371518/in-ruby-is-there-an-array-method-that-combines-select-and-map/56565188#answer-56565188).

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I usually use `map` and `compact` together along with my selection criteria as a postfix `if`. `compact` gets rid of the nils.

```
jruby-1.5.0 > [1,1,1,2,3,4].map{|n| n*3 if n==1}    
 => [3, 3, 3, nil, nil, nil] 


jruby-1.5.0 > [1,1,1,2,3,4].map{|n| n*3 if n==1}.compact
 => [3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Ah-ha, I was trying to figure out how to ignore nils returned by my map block. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I love compact. it unobtrusively sits out there and does its job. I also prefer this method to chaining enumerable functions for simple selection criteria because it is very declarative.

Comment: Lots of good answers here, but this one eliminates the need to chain select and map together which is excellent. Thanks!

Comment: I was unsure if `map` + `compact` would really perform better than `inject` and posted my benchmark results to a related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310426/list-comprehension-in-ruby/5046057#5046057

Comment: this will remove all nils, both the original nils and those that fail your criteria. So watch out

Comment: It doesn't *entirely* eliminate chaining `map` and `select`, it's just that `compact` is a special case `reject` that works on nils and performs somewhat better due to having been implemented directly in C.

Answer (score 102):

**Ruby 2.7+**

*There is now!*

Ruby 2.7 is introducing `filter_map` for this exact purpose. It's idiomatic and performant, and I'd expect it to become the norm very soon.

For example:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 5, 8, 10, 13]
enum.filter_map { |i| i * 2 if i.even? }
# => [4, 16, 20]
```

Here's a [good read on the subject](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/05/25/ruby-2-7-enumerable-filter-map.html).

Hope that's useful to someone!

Comment: No matter how often I upgrade, a cool feature is always in the next version.

Comment: Nice. One problem could be that since `filter`, `select` and `find_all` are synonymous, just as `map` and `collect` are, it might be hard to remember the name of this method. Is it `filter_map`, `select_collect`, `find_all_map` or `filter_collect` ?

Comment: This definitely should be the accepted answer in 2021 with Ruby 2.7!  Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 57):

You can use `reduce` for this, which requires only one pass:

```
[1,1,1,2,3,4].reduce([]) { |a, n| a.push(n*3) if n==1; a }
=> [3, 3, 3]
```

In other words, initialize the state to be what you want (in our case, an empty list to fill: `[]`), then always make sure to return this value with modifications for each element in the original list (in our case, the modified element pushed to the list).

This is the most efficient since it only loops over the list with one pass (`map` + `select` or `compact` requires two passes).

In your case:

```
def example
  results = @lines.reduce([]) do |lines, line|
    lines.push( ...(line) ) if ...
    lines
  end
  return results.uniq.sort
end
```

Comment: Doesn't `each_with_object` make a little more sense? You don't have to return the array at the end of each iteration of the block. You can simply do `my_array.each_with_object([]) { |i, a| a << i if i.condition }`.

Comment: @henrebotha Perhaps it does. I'm coming from a functional background, that's why I found `reduce` first 

Comment: Never forget `reduce` (`left fold`) is what makes all these maps and filters tick.  Syntax sugars have their value too though.

Answer (score 22):

Another different way of approaching this is using the new (relative to this question) `Enumerator::Lazy`:

```
def example
  @lines.lazy
        .select { |line| line.property == requirement }
        .map    { |line| transforming_method(line) }
        .uniq
        .sort
end
```

The `.lazy` method returns a lazy enumerator. Calling `.select` or `.map` on a lazy enumerator returns another lazy enumerator. Only once you call `.uniq` does it actually force the enumerator and return an array. So what effectively happens is your `.select` and `.map` calls are combined into one - you only iterate over `@lines` once to do both `.select` and `.map`.

My instinct is that Adam's `reduce` method will be a little faster, but I think this is far more readable.

---

The primary consequence of this is that no intermediate array objects are created for each subsequent method call. In a normal `@lines.select.map` situation, `select` returns an array which is then modified by `map`, again returning an array. By comparison, the lazy evaluation only creates an array once. This is useful when your initial collection object is large. It also empowers you to work with infinite enumerators - e.g. `random_number_generator.lazy.select(&:odd?).take(10)`.

Comment: To each their own. With my kind of solution I can glance at the method names and immediately know that I am going to transform a subset of the input data, make it unique, and sort it. `reduce` as a "do everything" transformation always feels fairly messy to me.

Comment: @henrebotha: Forgive me if I've misunderstood what you meant, but this is a very important point: it's **not correct** to say that "you only iterate over `@lines` once to do both `.select` and `.map`". Using `.lazy` does not mean chained operations operations on a lazy enumerator will get "collapsed" into one single iteration. This is a common misunderstanding of lazy evaluation w.r.t chaining operations over a collection. (You can test this by adding a `puts` statement to the beginning of the `select` and `map` blocks in the first example. You'll find that they print the same number of lines)

Comment: @pje: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].lazy.select { |i| puts "select"; i.odd? }.map { |i| puts "map"; i.to_s }.uniq.sort` prints "select" five times and "map" three times, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @henrebotha: and if you remove the `.lazy` it prints the same number of times. That's my point—your `map` block and your `select` block are executed the same number of times in the lazy and eager versions. The lazy version does not "combine your `.select` and `.map` calls"

Comment: @pje: _In effect_ `lazy` combines them because an element that fails the `select` condition does not get passed to the `map`. In other words: prepending `lazy` is roughly equivalent to replacing `select` and `map` with a single `reduce([])`, and "intelligently" making `select`'s block a precondition to inclusion in `reduce`'s result.

Comment: @henrebotha: I think that's a misleading analogy for lazy evaluation in general, because laziness does not change the time complexity of this algorithm. This is my point: in every case, a lazy select-then-map will always perform the same number of computations as its eager version. It doesn't speed anything up, it just changes the order of execution of each iteration—the last function in the chain "pulls" values as needed from the previous functions in reverse order.

Comment: @pje: Nowhere did I claim it changes the time complexity. In fact, my post explicitly states that this will be slower than making a single pass with `reduce`. But I'll grant your objection. Why don't you go ahead and edit my answer to be a bit less misleading?

Comment: The *time* complexity is the same in that the lazy/eager versions both make the same number of operations, but the *space* complexity is less since only one additional array is ever initialized with the lazy version.

Comment: I agree that the wording `you only iterate over @lines once to do both .select and .map` is incorrect. `#lazy`, `#select` and `#map` are all creating enumerators here, so there is actually more enumerations being performed with this solution because of the extra lazy enumerator. The answer shows that `reduce` is expected to be faster, but I expect this is also slower than most/all the other answers. I do love the rest of this answer though AND it introduced me to (allowed me to stumble upon) lazy enumeration in ruby. Thanks!

Comment: What is the right way to run this code if I don't need `uniq` and `sort`? 
Is this how you'd do it `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].lazy.select { |i| puts "select"; i.odd? }.map { |i| puts "map"; i.to_s }.to_a`?

Answer (score 13):

If you have a `select` that can use the `case` operator (`===`), `grep` is a good alternative:

```
p [1,2,'not_a_number',3].grep(Integer){|x| -x } #=> [-1, -2, -3]

p ['1','2','not_a_number','3'].grep(/\D/, &:upcase) #=> ["NOT_A_NUMBER"]
```

If we need more complex logic we can create lambdas:

```
my_favourite_numbers = [1,4,6]

is_a_favourite_number = -> x { my_favourite_numbers.include? x }

make_awesome = -> x { "***#{x}***" }

my_data = [1,2,3,4]

p my_data.grep(is_a_favourite_number, &make_awesome) #=> ["***1***", "***4***"]
```

Comment: It's not an alternative - it's the only correct answer to the question.

Comment: @inopinatus: [Not anymore](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/05/25/ruby-2-7-enumerable-filter-map.html). This is still a good answer, though. I don't remember seeing grep with a block otherwise.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure there is one. The [Enumerable module](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html), which adds `select` and `map`,  doesn't show one.

You'd be required to pass in two blocks to the `select_and_transform` method, which would be a bit unintuitive IMHO.

Obviously, you could just chain them together, which is more readable:

```
transformed_list = lines.select{|line| ...}.map{|line| ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple Answer:

If you have n records, and you want to `select` and `map` based on condition then

```
records.map { |record| record.attribute if condition }.compact
```

Here, attribute is whatever you want from the record and condition you can put any check.

compact is to flush the unnecessary nil's which came out of that if condition

Comment: You can use the same with unless condition too. As my friend asked.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can do it like this:

```
lines.map { |line| do_some_action if check_some_property  }.reject(&:nil?)
```

Or even better:

```
lines.inject([]) { |all, line| all << line if check_some_property; all }
```

Comment: `reject(&:nil?)` is basically the same as `compact`.

Comment: Yeah, so the inject method is even better.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this way is more readable, because splits the filter conditions and mapped value while remaining clear that the actions are connected:

```
results = @lines.select { |line|
  line.should_include?
}.map do |line|
  line.value_to_map
end
```

And, in your specific case, eliminate the `result` variable all together:

```
def example
  @lines.select { |line|
    line.should_include?
  }.map { |line|
    line.value_to_map
  }.uniq.sort
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def example
  @lines.select {|line| ... }.map {|line| ... }.uniq.sort
end
```

In Ruby 1.9 and 1.8.7, you can also chain and wrap iterators by simply not passing a block to them:

```
enum.select.map {|bla| ... }
```

But it's not really possible in this case, since the types of the block return values of `select` and `map` don't match up. It makes more sense for something like this:

```
enum.inject.with_index {|(acc, el), idx| ... }
```

AFAICS, the best you can do is the first example.

Here's a small example:

```
%w[a b 1 2 c d].map.select {|e| if /[0-9]/ =~ e then false else e.upcase end }
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

%w[a b 1 2 c d].select.map {|e| if /[0-9]/ =~ e then false else e.upcase end }
# => ["A", "B", false, false, "C", "D"]
```

But what you *really* want is `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`.

Comment: I did a very brief web search last night for "method chaining in Ruby" and it seemed like it wasn't supported well. Tho, I probably should have tried it...   also, why do you say the types of the block arguments don't match up? In my example both blocks are taking a line of text from my array, right?

Comment: @Seth Petry-Johnson: Yeah, sorry, I meant the return values. `select` returns a Boolean-ish value that decides whether to keep the element or not, `map` returns the transformed value. The transformed value itself is probably going to be truthy, so all elements get selected.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using my library [Rearmed Ruby](https://github.com/westonganger/rearmed-rb) in which I have added the method `Enumerable#select_map`. Heres an example:

```
items = [{version: "1.1"}, {version: nil}, {version: false}]

items.select_map{|x| x[:version]} #=> [{version: "1.1"}]
# or without enumerable monkey patch
Rearmed.select_map(items){|x| x[:version]}
```

Comment: `select_map` in this library just implements the same `select { |i| ... }.map { |i| ... }` strategy from many answers above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to not create two different arrays, you can use `compact!` but be careful about it.

```
array = [1,1,1,2,3,4]
new_array = map{|n| n*3 if n==1}
new_array.compact!
```

Interestingly, `compact!` does an in place removal of nil. The return value of `compact!` is the same array if there were changes but nil if there were no nils.

```
array = [1,1,1,2,3,4]
new_array = map{|n| n*3 if n==1}.tap { |array| array.compact! }
```

Would be a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

Your version:

```
def example
  matchingLines = @lines.select{ |line| ... }
  results = matchingLines.map{ |line| ... }
  return results.uniq.sort
end
```

My version:

```
def example
  results = {}
  @lines.each{ |line| results[line] = true if ... }
  return results.keys.sort
end
```

This will do 1 iteration (except the sort), and has the added bonus of keeping uniqueness (if you don't care about uniq, then just make results an array and `results.push(line) if ...`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a example. It is not the same as your problem, but may be what you want, or can give a clue to your solution:

```
def example
  lines.each do |x|
    new_value = do_transform(x)
    if new_value == some_thing
      return new_value    # here jump out example method directly.
    else
      next                # continue next iterate.
    end
  end
end
```