# Is there a way to apply map and delete_if to an array in a single method call (Rails 3 activerecord)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dictionary, activerecord

I have 3 models `User`, `Post` and `Favorite`. A `user` may have many `favorite_posts`. The association is polymorphic as the `user` may `favorite` a few other classes as well. Currently I have this method defined for retrieving the user's favorite posts.

```
def favorite_posts
  favorites.includes(:favoriteable).where(favoriteable_type: 'Post').map(&:favoriteable)
end
```

I recently added an attribute to `Post` called `flagged`. If this attribute is `true` I would like to remove this from the user's favorites. I could add a `delete_if` method after I call `map(&:favoriteable)`.

```
def favorite_posts
  favorites.includes(:favoriteable).where(favoriteable_type: 'Post').map(&:favoriteable).delete_if{|post| post.flagged == true}
end
```

I wondered if it would be possible to both `map(&:favoriteable)` and delete the post if it were flagged in one method call?

I know you may add a condition to the `map` call but from my experiments the method would return an array of the same length but with `nil` values in place of the flagged `posts`. Even if it can't be done in one call, a faster technique would be nice to know also.

Thanks and let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Do you want to delete that objects from the database or just from the array? If you do not want the objects in the array, why don't you change your query and do not load them in a first place?

Comment: Just from the array. I am performing the query on the `Favorite` model but using the `map` method to just give back the `posts` in the results. I could probably do some more complex join but I'm not sure that it is necessarily faster to do that as the `Post` table could be enormous but the array of `favorite_posts` should never grow extremely large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to conditionally collect elements from a collection in a single call. Here are some alternatives.

Use the `compact` method with `map`.

```
def favorite_posts
  favorites.includes(:favoriteable).where(favoriteable_type: 'Post')
           .map { |f| f.favoriteable unless post.flagged }.compact
end
```

Use `select` with `map`.

```
def favorite_posts
  favorites.includes(:favoriteable).where(favoriteable_type: 'Post')
           .select { |f| !f.favoriteable.flagged }.map(&:favoriteable)
end
```

If you have no qualms with manually constructing your results, use `each_with_object`

```
def favorite_posts
  favorites.includes(:favoriteable).where(favoriteable_type: 'Post')
           .each_with_object([]) { |f, posts| posts.push(f.favoriteable) unless post.flagged }
end
```

Use a join.

```
def favorite_posts
  Post.joins(:favoriteable).where(favoriteable: { user_id: id })
      .where(flagged: false)
end
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371518/in-ruby-is-there-an-array-method-that-combines-select-and-map) for a similar discussion.

Comment: I'm gonna leave this open for a little while but I think that `compact` after the `map` call is better than my method.

Comment: cool, i'll try that one out too and report back. Memorial day weekend, and work is really grinding on me with some deadlines, might not be reporting back until next week.  :/  thanks though! I will definitely let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Array#select instead of map and delete_if together.

```
def favorite_posts
    favorites.includes(:favoriteable).where(favoriteable_type: 'Post').select{|post| post.favoriteable && post.flagged == true}
end
```

Alternatively you could use a condition with map and then call Array#compact which eliminates any nil values.

Comment: I think `favorites.where(...)` will return objects of class Favorite, so just using one `select` would not work in this case.

Comment: `Post` does not have an attribute `favoriteable`. `Favorite` has attributes `favoriteable_id` and `favoriteable_type` which I guess through some activerecord/rails magic is accessible simply as `favorite.favoriteable`.