# Is there a way to Refactor the following code in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have written a piece of code and need to refactor it.

```
Reviewing.where(reviewing_status_condition(employee_ids)).group(:employee_id).count.map{ 
|employee_id, reviewings_count_per_employee|
    employee_id if reviewings_count_per_employee >= @cycle.min_required_anon_feedback
  }.compact
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this refactoring?

Comment: Reduce the time complexity each caused by the map and compact together

Comment: Have you tested this code and ensured that it actually works before refactoring? I can imagine `.count.map` being problematic since `.count` creates a count query and returns an integer - yet you're calling map on it like it was a collection.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of solving this issue in Ruby you could also opt to let your database handle the problem. However to do this you first need to know what your query is going to be, I would go for something like:

```sql
SELECT reviewings.employee_id
FROM reviewings
WHERE ...
GROUP BY reviewings.employee_id
HAVING COUNT(reviewings.id) >= <your value>
```

This can be achieved with the following code:

```
reviewings = Reviewing.arel_table

employee_ids = Reviewing
               .where(reviewing_status_condition(employee_ids))
               .group(:employee_id)
               .having(reviewings[:id].count.gteq(@cycle.min_required_anon_feedback))
               .pluck(:employee_id)
```

By limiting the data returned from the database you can leave out the data manipulation on the Ruby side.

If you'd like to know more about arel I suggest checking out their [readme](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/file/README.md).

---

Let me add a fun comparison. Let's say you'll order some pizzas.

- You are currently doing the following: You call your pizza place and ask them to send one of every pizza. When the pizzas arrive at your home you and your comrades need to figure out what pizzas to keep and which ones to throw away before eating them.
- I'm suggesting: Look at the menu and figure out what pizzas you need up front. Order only what you need. When the pizzas arrive at your home all decisions are already made and handled (assuming a correct delivery) and you can simply enjoy your pizza.

Comment: Is there no possibility to rather reduce the use of map and then compact with just one enumerator method that will solve the issue?

Comment: @MaheshMesta I've added [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58959967/3982562) addressing this in Ruby.

Comment: Good answer. Spending time trying to fix the iteration in Ruby is most likely a complete waste of time as the issue is really going to be pulling the all the data out of the database in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Step one for me would be to move the `where` clause and `group` to a named scope. That will reduce the initial segment:

```
Reviewing.where(reviewing_status_condition(employee_ids)).group(:employee_id).count
```

to something more like:

```
Reviewing.reviewing_count(reviewing_status_condition(employee_ids))
```

which is not a lot shorter but does significantly improve the separation of the implementation from execution.

Step two depends on what version of Ruby you are using. Pre 2.7 the correct way to do the `map` and `compact` step you are doing is what you have or could be done with `select` and `map` instead but Ruby 2.7 introduces `filter_map` which is a single step combination of what you have here.

See "[In Ruby, is there an Array method that combines 'select' and 'map'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371518/in-ruby-is-there-an-array-method-that-combines-select-and-map/56565188#56565188)" for more details on `filter_map`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't change the data supply like suggested in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58958152/3982562). I would change your `.map{...}.compact` to `.select{...}.keys`, since it better communicates what you are trying to achieve with your code. You are filtering/selecting certain employee ids based upon reviewing count.

```
reviewings_count_per_employee = Reviewing.where(reviewing_status_condition(employee_ids)).group(:employee_id).count
```

```
employee_ids = reviewings_count_per_employee
               .select { |_id, count| count >= @cycle.min_required_anon_feedback }
               .keys
```

I'm not sure if this reduces the time complexity, but it certainly improves readability. I wouldn't worry to much about time complexity as long as you're in the linear realm of things. If `select` is `O(N)` and `keys` is `O(N)` then you end up with `O(2N)` which is not really an issue. If you want to keep your code `O(N)` the following does the trick.

```
employee_ids = []
reviewings_count_per_employee.each do |id, count| 
  employee_ids << id if count >= @cycle.min_required_anon_feedback
end
```

However I personally find the solution with `select` more readable than the `each` solution. And although this might save some CPU load, your brain has to  work harder to understand what you've written in 6-12 months time when you revisit your code.