# List comprehension in Haskell, Python and Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, haskell, list-comprehension

I have started looking at the [project Euler site](http://projecteuler.net/problems) as a way to learn Haskell, and improve my Python and Ruby. I think the Haskell and Python versions are ok, but I'm sure there must be a cleaner way for Ruby.

This is not about how can I make one language look like another one.

This is [Problem 1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1):

> Q: Add all the natural numbers below one thousand that are multiples of 3 or 5.

Haskell:

```
sum [ x | x <- [1..999], mod x 3 == 0 || mod x 5 == 0 ]
```

Python:

```
sum ( [ x for x in range(1,1000) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0 ] )
```

Ruby:

```
(1..999) . map {|x| x if x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 } . compact . inject(:+)
```

They all give the same answer.

---

OK, so Python can become:

```
sum ( x for x in range(1,1000) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0 )
```

it is now a generator (a good thing as we are not storing the list)

but even more fun is:

```
sum( set(range(0,1000,3)) | set(range(0,1000,5)) )
```

For some reason I was looking at this again and tried a summation approach which should be constant time. In Python 3:

```
def step_sum(mn,mx,step):
    amax = mx - (mx - mn) % step
    return (mn + amax) * ((1 + ((amax - mn) / step)) / 2)

step_sum(3,999,3) + step_sum(5,999,5) - step_sum(15,999,15)
```

Ruby can become:

```
(1..999) . select {|x| x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0} . inject(:+)
```

or

```
(1..999) . select {|x| x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0} . reduce(:+)
```

I am presuming as unlike `map`, `select` doesn't produce 'nul' and therefore there is no need to call `compact`. nice.

Haskell can also be:

```
let ƒ n = sum [0,n..999] in ƒ 3 + ƒ 5 - ƒ 15
```

or to be clearer:

```
let ƒ n = sum [ 0 , n .. 999 ] in ƒ 3 + ƒ 5 - ƒ (lcm 3 5)
```

as a function that lets us provide the two numbers ourselves:

```
ƒ :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a
ƒ x y = let ƒ n = sum [0,n..999] in ƒ x + ƒ y - ƒ (lcm x y)
```

Comment: So what is this supposed to do?

Comment: Ruby always remind me of Perl... Powerful and compact syntax, but sometimes you have a hard time reading your own code after a few weeks.

Comment: Hi, I don't know about ruby, and this doesn't answer your question but... Congrats on picking up Project Euler, it's awesome... there's a constant time solution to that particular problem if you want to optimize a bit ;) If you don't know about Summation, check it out, it'll come very handy further on.

Comment: In Python you can remove the square brackets.

Comment: @Jwosty: sum all numbers from 1 to 999 divisible by 3 or 5.

Comment: @Jwosty you mean the code or are you being philosophical about the question? if it is the code... then it is supposed to provide an answer to the question 'Q'.

Comment: @eumiro: removing the square brackets will transform the list comprehension into a generator, which is a very good idea (performance-wise) if you are not going to store the list.

Comment: @eumiro does this mean that it is no longer 'list comprehension' or is the list the range(1,1000)?

Comment: @pcalcao I will certainly look into Summation... Yeah the project is great fun!

Comment: @user969617: if you're using Python 2.X `range()` indeed constructs a list, although that doesn't make that a list comprehension; it's still a generator expression, which works a lot like a list but only calculates (and gives you) an item at a time. You can use `xrange()` to get a generator there too (that's better most of the time).

Comment: @user969617: if you're using Python 3 `range()` acts like `xrange()` in Python 2 by default, so no undesired lists are ever constructed fully in memory.

Comment: @user969617 wow, I skipped right over that line x_x

Comment: Here is a nice discussion on some alternatives to the list comprehension idiom in the Ruby world: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310426/list-comprehension-in-ruby

Comment: @Jwosty :) just glad I didn't need to get all deep and meaningfull

Comment: You can't generalize the Haskell solution for arbitrary numbers, see my updated answer.

Comment: In Python2, you have to be aware of the range function as it constructs a list and stores it to memory, making your generator expression less efficient. Instead, use xrange() with the same arguments, but it returns a generator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Haskell I like

```
let s n = sum [0,n..999] in s 3 + s 5 - s 15
```

or

```
sum $ filter ((>1).(gcd 15)) [0..999]
```

For fun the Rube-Goldberg version:

```
import Data.Bits

sum $ zipWith (*) [1..999] $ zipWith (.|.) (cycle [0,0,1]) (cycle [0,0,0,0,1])
```

---

Okay, explanation time.

The first version defines a little function s that sums up all multiples of n up to 999. If we sum all multiples of 3 and all multiples of 5, we included all multiples of 15 twice (once in every list), hence we need to subtract them one time.

The second version uses the fact that 3 and 5 are primes. If a number contains one or both of the factors 3 and 5, the gcd of this number and 15 will be 3, 5 or 15, so in every case the gcd will be bigger than one. For other numbers without a common factor with 15 the gcd becomes 1. This is a nice trick to test both conditions in one step. But be careful, it won't work for arbitrary numbers, e.g. when we had 4 and 9, the test `gdc x 36 > 1` won't work, as `gcd 6 36 == 6`, but neither `mod 6 4 == 0` nor `mod 6 9 == 0`.

The third version is quite funny. `cycle` repeats a list over and over. `cycle [0,0,1]` codes the "divisibility pattern" for 3, and `cycle [0,0,0,0,1]` does the same for 5. Then we "or" both lists together using `zipWith`, which gives us `[0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1...]`. Now we use `zipWith` again to multiply this with the actual numbers, resulting in `[0,0,3,0,5,6,0,0,9,10,0,12...]`. Then we just add it up.

Knowing different ways to do the same thing might be wasteful for other languages, but for Haskell it is essential. You need to spot patterns, pick up tricks and idioms, and play around a lot in order to gain the mental flexibility to use this language effectively. Challenges like the project Euler problems are a good opportunity to do so.

Comment: could you explain you answers a bit (1 day of haskell means everything is new to me)... the first seems to be a recursive function. 15 being the least common multiple? [0,n..999] would be the pattern... ie 0,3,6,9 ... ] and n is provided with a value in s 3 ... s 5 ...

Comment: @user969617: Principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @Vitus I have edited my question to include this Haskell code. It was only after staring at it for a minute that it clicked :)

Comment: @user969617: Disregard my previous (deleted) comment, I didn't notice the leading `let`. :)

Comment: @Landei thanks for the explanation. I have updated my original question to include the first example you included - as I worked out how to use it. Learning Haskell is funny - on the one had it goes against what I expect things should be, while on the other it is exactly what I think things should be (ie... functions / when coming from non functional languages)... It also looks beautiful.

Answer (score 4):

Try this for Ruby:

```
(1..999).select {|x| x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0}.reduce(:+)
```

Or a little different approach:

```
(1..999).reduce(0) {|m, x| (x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0) ? m+x : m }
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I prefer 'reduce' to 'inject' though.

Comment: Yep, `reduce` is a little shorter and more intuitively named.

Comment: `select` is very clear as long as you don't need to process the selected value (then you need a `select` + `map`), that's where list-comprehensions shine. In Ruby you can write a `map_select` but it's not as beautiful (not to mention nested list-comprehensions).

Comment: I'm not that keen on using `or` and `and` like this. See http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/

Comment: Also, you second example adds those that are multiples of both 3 and 5.

Comment: Whoops, fixed, thanks! About `or` vs. `||`... the place it matters is in expressions with potential precedence ambiguities, such as assignments. In this case it's simply more readable :)

Answer (score 2):

Not a list comprehension, I know, but to solve that I would use:

```
3*((999/3)**2+999/3)/2+5*((999/5)**2+999/5)/2-15*((999/15)**2+999/15)/2
```

Faster then any list comprehension one might come up with, and works in any language ;)

Only posting to show another way of looking at the same problem using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation.

Comment: That's slow!... what about `print 233168`?

Comment: well... I guess the difference is that only 999 is hard-coded, right? same as the list comprehensions above?... I know it would be **really** hard to refactor that magic number into a function parameter...

Comment: haskell returns: 233366.40000000002
python and ruby : 233168

Comment: Hmmm... haven't done any haskelling, I suppose that has to do with division being returned as a floating point number. In ruby and python a division of two integers is automatically assumed as an integer division.

Comment: pcalcao is correct. Integer division in haskell is `div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`. Compare with `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`. 
Same thing with `(**) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a` vs `(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is a better Ruby one:

```
(1..999).select{|x| x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0}.reduce(:+)
```

Comment: detail: `reduce(0, :+)` makes no assumptions about how many values will be sum.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
(1...1000).inject(0) do |sum, i|
  if (i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0)
    sum + i
  else
    sum
  end
```