# Does Ruby have something like Python's list comprehensions?

Tags: python, ruby, programming-languages

Python has a nice feature:

```
print([j**2 for j in [2, 3, 4, 5]]) # => [4, 9, 16, 25]
```

In Ruby it's even simpler:

```
puts [2, 3, 4, 5].map{|j| j**2}
```

but if it's about nested loops Python looks more convenient.

In Python we can do this:

```
digits = [1, 2, 3]
chars = ['a', 'b', 'c']    
print([str(d)+ch for d in digits for ch in chars if d >= 2 if ch == 'a'])    
# => ['2a', '3a']
```

The equivalent in Ruby is:

```
digits = [1, 2, 3]
chars = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list = []
digits.each do |d|
    chars.each do |ch|
        list.push d.to_s << ch if d >= 2 && ch == 'a'
    end
end
puts list
```

Does Ruby have something similar?

Comment: Something similar discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310426/list-comprehension-in-ruby

Comment: The short version is that Ruby has a few different things that are sort of similar, but nothing that's exactly the same, and nothing quite as concise (or readable). The long version… is the answer RBK linked to.

Comment: @RBK well yes, but it's not about nested loops (1+ arrays)

Comment: Some of the answers to that question scale to nested loops, some don't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The common way in Ruby is to properly combine [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) and [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) methods to achieve the same:

```
digits.product(chars).select{ |d, ch| d >= 2 && ch == 'a' }.map(&:join)
```

This is only 4 or so characters longer than the list comprehension and just as expressive (IMHO of course, but since list comprehensions are just a special application of the list monad, one could argue that it's probably possible to adequately rebuild that using Ruby's collection methods), while not needing any special syntax.

Answer (score 2):

As you know Ruby has no syntactic sugar for list-comprehensions, so the closer you can get is by using blocks in imaginative ways. People have proposed different ideas, take a look at [lazylist](http://flori.github.com/lazylist/) and [verstehen](https://github.com/corbanbrook/verstehen) approaches, both support nested comprehensions with conditions:

```
require 'lazylist'
list { [x, y] }.where(:x => [1, 2], :y => [3, 4]) { x+y>4 }.to_a
#=> [[1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]]

require 'verstehen'
list { [x, y] }.for(:x).in { [1, 2] }.for(:y).in { [3, 4] }.if { x+y>4 }.comprehend
#=> [[1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]]
```

Of course that's not what you'd call idiomatic Ruby, so it's usually safer to use the typical `product` + `select` + `map` approach.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by RBK above, [List comprehension in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310426/list-comprehension-in-ruby) provides a whole slew of different ways to do things sort of like list comprehensions in Ruby.

None of them explicitly describe nested loops, but at least some of them can be nested quite easily.

For example, the accepted answer by Robert Gamble suggests adding an Array#comprehend method.

```
class Array
  def comprehend(&block)
    return self if block.nil?
    self.collect(&block).compact
  end
end
```

Having done that, you can write your code as:

```
digits.comprehend{|d| chars.comprehend{|ch| d.to_s+ch if ch =='a'} if d>=2}
```

Compare to the Python code:

```
[str(d)+ch for d in digits for ch in chars if d >= 2 if ch == 'a']
```

The differences are pretty minor:

1. The Ruby code is a bit longer. But that's mostly just the fact that "comprehend" is spelled out; you can always call it something shorter if you want.
2. The Ruby code puts things in a different order—the arrays come at the beginning instead of in the middle. But if you think about it, that's exactly what you'd expect, and want, because of the "everything is a method" philosophy.
3. The Ruby code requires nested braces for nested comprehensions. I can't think of an obvious way around this that doesn't make things worse (you don't want to call "[str,digits].comprehend2" or anything…).

Of course the real strength of Python here is that if you decide you want to evaluate the list lazily, you can convert your comprehension into a generator expression just by removing the brackets (or turning them into parentheses, depending on the context). But even there, you could create an Array#lazycomprehend or something.