# Erlang vs Ruby list comprehensions

Tags: ruby, erlang, list-comprehension

I just started to learn Erlang, and really like their list comprehension syntax, for example:

```
Weather = [{toronto, rain}, {montreal, storms}, {london, fog}, {paris, sun}, {boston, fog}, {vancounver, snow}].                          
FoggyPlaces = [X || {X, fog} <- Weather].
```

In this case, `FoggyPlaces` will evaluate to "london" and "boston".

What's the best way to do this in Ruby?

For example, an Array like (very common, I believe):

```
 weather = [{city: 'toronto', weather: :rain}, {city: 'montreal', weather: :storms}, {city: 'london', weather: :fog}, {city: 'paris', weather: :sun}, {city: 'boston', weather: :fog}, {city: 'vancounver', weather: :snow}]
```

The best I got 'til now is:

```
weather.collect {|w| w[:city] if w[:weather] == :fog }.compact
```

But in this case, I have to call `compact` to remove `nil` values, and the example itself is not that readable as Erlang.

And even more, in the Erlang example, both `city` and `weather` are atoms. I don't even know how to get something that makes sense and looks good like this in Ruby.

Comment: it's a FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319429/does-ruby-have-something-like-pythons-list-comprehensionsexample, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310426/list-comprehension-in-ruby, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737525/list-comprehension-in-haskell-python-and-ruby.

Comment: erlang is very declarative and symbolic, very close to human

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, your data structures aren't equivalent. The equivalent Ruby data structure to your Erlang example would be more like

```
weather = [[:toronto, :rain], [:montreal, :storms], [:london, :fog], 
            [:paris, :sun], [:boston, :fog], [:vancouver, :snow]]
```

Secondly, yes, Ruby doesn't have list comprehensions nor pattern matching. So, the example *will* probably be more complex. Your list comprehension first filters all foggy cities, then projects the name. Let's do the same in Ruby:

```
weather.select {|_, weather| weather == :fog }.map(&:first)
# => [:london, :boston]
```

However, Ruby is centered around objects, but you are using abstract data types. With a more object-oriented data abstraction, the code would probably look more like

```
weather.select(&:foggy?).map(&:city)
```

which isn't too bad, is it?

Comment: Erlang tuples are not equivalent with Ruby hashes?

Comment: +1 for bit about objects. Direct translation is usually not idiomatic translation.

Comment: No, Erlang `dict`s are equivalent to Ruby `Hash`es. There really is no direct equivalent to tuples in Ruby, the closest you can get is an array.

Comment: @caarlos0 Don't let the curly-brace syntax fool you: Tuples are not the same data type as Hashes.

Comment: hm, got that.. I didn't see dicts yet, I just started :) thanks for the simple explanation.